# How can I emulate a GPU for testing code written in Pytorch?

Tags: pytorch, gpu

Often, I code on my laptop which is not equipped with a GPU (MacBook, if it makes a difference). Then files are transferred to a server with a GPU. I just want to perform a sanity-check on my code, before running it on the server, in order to avoid errors related to tensors being on different devices. I am looking for a gpu emulator, which takes in some tenosrs and outputs some other random tensors.

Comment: Thanks, I found a simulator named GPGPU-Sim, which is going to apparently solve my problem. I have not tried it, yet. I will try it and update if it is successfull.

Answer (score -2):

Just add `.to('cuda:0')` to your model which inherits `nn.Module` and any tensor you created within the forward/backward pass.

Note that `cuda:0` means the gpu of index 0.

Moreover, I'd like to define a hyper parameter dictionary to pass to the model, one can easily define `hparams['device'] = 'cpu'/'cuda:0'/'cuda:1'` in the dict, and when initialize the model, the property `self.device = hparams['device']` is set, so that any tensor/module in the model can be easily migrated to any device as configured by adding `.to(self.device)`.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I normally do. Unfortunately, there are too many details, and some might be forgotten. I need a way to check before running the code.